# Is there an automated way to see if AWS account has Premium Support Subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3, aws-cli

I have multiple AWS accounts and need an automated way (CLI or SDK) to find out if the account has a Premium Support Subscription.

Essentially I want to know whether I can use cloudwatch events from Trusted Advisor to trigger Lambda functions on a particular account.

On the cli I can run:

```
aws support <command>
```

and will get an error if Premium Support isn't enabled, but is there a better way to find this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this out but you can use `Boto3` SDK (Python). From: [AWS Support](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/support.html)

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('support')
```

These are the available methods:

- describe_cases()
- describe_communications()
- describe_services()
- describe_severity_levels()
- describe_trusted_advisor_check_refresh_statuses()
- describe_trusted_advisor_check_result()
- describe_trusted_advisor_check_summaries()
- describe_trusted_advisor_checks()
- refresh_trusted_advisor_check()
- resolve_case()

I just tried few APIs. All of them failed due to lack of Premium support. So, you are out of luck.

```
>>> client.describe_services()
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (SubscriptionRequiredException) when calling the DescribeServices operation: AWS Premium Support Subscription is required to use this service.

>>> client.describe_trusted_advisor_checks(language='en')
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (SubscriptionRequiredException) when calling the DescribeTrustedAdvisorChecks operation: AWS Premium Support Subscription is required to use this service.
```

Comment: I can use that in the same way as the cli, but when running against an account without premium support it will raise a botocore exception. I could handle the exception in the code which will tell me whether it's enabled, but I'm wondering if there is a better way of finding out whether premium support is enabled

Comment: @tkwargs I just updated my answer. Looks like there is no better way to check.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer above I wrote this code. Worked for me, hope it helps!

```
import boto3
import botocore

def has_premium_support():     
    try:
        client = boto3.client("support")
        client.describe_cases()
        return True
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as ex:
        if ex.response["Error"]["Code"] == "SubscriptionRequiredException":
            return False
        raise
```